# Почему не работает функция?

Tags: javascript

Цель анонимной функции - изменить ширину и высоту body, так как у вложенных элементов ширина и высота - в процентах от body. Но функция ничего не изменяет: ни высоту, ни ширину.

```
var UserWindow = getSize()

window.onload = function () {
        var body = document.getElementById("bod");
        body.style.width = UserWindow.width;
        body.style.height = UserWindow.height;

    }

function getSize() {
    var LocalObj = {
        width: window.outerWidth,
        height: window.outerHeight
    }
    return LocalObj
}
```

Comment: Уточните, какая функция, что вы хотели сделать, что ожидали получить и что получили.

Comment: Работет все, если на боди висит айдишник bod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `var body = document.body;`.
Во-вторых, `body.style.width = UserWindow.width + 'px';`.
В-третьих, `window.onresize = function(){UserWindow = getSize();/* и меняем размер body */}`